# Html Newsletter issue Outlook 2016 - How to debug?

Tags: html, css, newsletter, outlook-2016

i have a bigger problem with my newsletter template. Outlook 2016 shows an error that I cannot debug. In all other browsers and mail clients this error does not occur at all.

I have two screenshots attached. One shows the error in Outlook 2016. The other screenshot is normal from the Chrome Browser.

I also tried to export the mail from Outlook 2016, but as soon as I exported it doesn't show the error as msg file or html file.

Would be very grateful for any help

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        img {
            display: block;
            float: none;
            margin: 0 auto 20px !important;
        }
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; background:#000;">
<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center" 
bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width:600px;">
<tr>
    <td>
<![endif]-->
<div style="max-width:600px; margin:0 auto; background:#fff; ">
<div style="Margin:20px;">
    <!--[if mso]>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="160" align="left" 
 style="width:160px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0 20px 20px  0;">
    <![endif]-->
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6bkt2Qk.gif" align="left" width="140" height="140" 
  border="0"
         style="Margin: 0 20px 20px  0; background:#E79851;"/>
    <!--[if mso]>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <![endif]-->
    <p style="Margin:0px 0 0 0px; font:16px/1.25 sans-serif; color:#4CB3E8; text- 
    align:justify;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, aut eligendi                 
    dignissimos, illum eaque ut
        architecto quisquam! Odio, aliquam eligendi iste tempore beatae, deserunt! Officia 
    temporibus at, debitis
        excepturi porro mollitia aspernatur labore unde dolores quae blanditiis dignissimos 
    error aut iure magnam
        sed placeat impedit incidunt praesentium natus dolorum. Hic illum vitae iusto 
    aspernatur tempora voluptatem
        id dolor reiciendis amet ea iste similique fuga, accusamus quibusdam, atque itaque 
    quae sit dolorem
        asperiores facilis, fugit odio eveniet. Autem iusto nisi, minus sunt fuga quas sed 
    expedita incidunt veniam
        nobis id ab. Blanditiis ullam laboriosam, quibusdam fugiat repellat labore nulla 
    natus minima at, a
        veritatis nostrum dignissimos ipsa libero, voluptatem itaque!
    </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <!--[if mso]>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <![endif]-->
   </body>
   </html>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "How to debug?" — By making tiny tweaks, sending an email after each one, looking at it in Outlook, and googling lists of Outlook rendering bugs.

Comment: I've tried all that for a long time, but unfortunately I couldn't find the mistake with it. For me it doesn't make any sense what Outlook does. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Have a look at Litmus, but I think part of the problem is probably that Outlook uses the Word render engine for HTML